# Conditional Match field validator in Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I want to implement a conditional match field validator on my reactive form code but not sure how.

I have conditional code that hides that password fields based if the LoginType is not UserName Password

```
public userForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() { 
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
    this.userForm.get('loginType').valueChanges.subscribe(

    (loginType: string) => {
        this.userForm.get('password').setValidators([]);
        this.userForm.get('confirmPassword').setValidators([]);


        if (loginType== 'UsernamePassword') {   this.userForm.get('password').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.pattern(/^.*(?=.{8,30})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W]).*$/)]);
                this.userForm.get('confirmPassword').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.pattern(/^.*(?=.{8,30})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W]).*$/)]);
        }

        this.userForm.get('password').updateValueAndValidity();
        this.userForm.get('confirmPassword').updateValueAndValidity();

    }

    )
}
```

The above works

I want to implement a MatchValidator and I find the examples all uses method similar to [this](https://scotch.io/@ibrahimalsurkhi/match-password-validation-with-angular-2)

```
 this.form = fb.group({
     password: ['', Validators.required],
     confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
    }, {
      validator: PasswordValidation.MatchPassword // your validation method
    })
```

However I have no idea to say in my specific code conditionally as I refer either to the form with this.userForm or the control with this.userForm.get('controlName')

How do I add a MatchFieldValidator to my code when I use conditional logic with valueChanges.subscribe and updateValueAndValidity?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is to instead of having the hassle to set validators conditionally is to instead apply formgroup conditionally, where the validators are already set, you just remove / add formgroup(s) based on the condition.

Here's a sample:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  // build nested formgroups that you will conditionally apply / remove
  this.group1 = this.fb.group({
    password: ['', [....]],
    confirm_password: ['', [....]]
  }, { validator: PasswordValidation.MatchPassword })

  this.group2 = this.fb.group({
    some_other: ['', [...]],
  })
  // your parent form, with group1 set initially
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    toggler: [false], // this one toggles groups
    group1: this.group1
  })
}
```

Then you just listen to valueChanges of `toggler` (in your case `loginType`) and remove / add formGroup. Here `toggler` is a checkbox, so...

```ts
this.myForm.controls.toggler.valueChanges
  .subscribe(bool => {
    if (bool) {
      this.myForm.removeControl('group1');
      this.myForm.setControl('group2', this.group2)
    } else {
      this.myForm.removeControl('group2');
      this.myForm.setControl('group1', this.group1)
    }
    this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  });
```

Now you are instead applying the groups conditionally.

Here's a

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pcqpdr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)